# Birt - times along the xaxis

Tags: charts, birt

I have a chart with time along the x-axis.

I want the points on the x-axis to be relative to their actual place in time not 
equidistantly spaced according to the number of points - is there any way to do this?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Actually I just found the answer - there is a checkbox called 'Is Category Axis' which needs is checked by default and needs to be unchecked - hope this helps if you have the same problem.

Comment: +1 Would vote this up as the answer, except it hasn't been *entered* as an answer.